# Реализация двух полей ввода

Tags: 1с

1. Можно выбрать любой документ из ныне существующих с помощью (...и лупы)
2. Выбрать место на компьютере, чтобы загрузить данный файл.

Подскажите примерные действия, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

1) Создаешь ПолеВвода с типом "ДокументСсылка" в свойствах поля включаешь кнопку открытия

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду загрузку файла с ПК в 1с, тогда надо на форму поместить элемент поле вода. А в событие выбора прописать:

```
ДиалогФыбораФайла = Новый ДиалогВыбораФайла(РежимДиалогаВыбораФайла.Открытие);

ДиалогФыбораФайла.Фильтр = "Текстовый файл (*.txt)|*.txt";
ДиалогФыбораФайла.Заголовок = "Выберите файл для загрузки данных";
ДиалогФыбораФайла.ПредварительныйПросмотр     = Ложь;
ДиалогФыбораФайла.Расширение                  = "txt";
ДиалогФыбораФайла.ИндексФильтра               = 0;
ДиалогФыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла              = Элемент.Значение;
ДиалогФыбораФайла.ПроверятьСуществованиеФайла = Ложь;

Если ДиалогФыбораФайла.Выбрать() Тогда
    Элемент.Значение = ДиалогФыбораФайла.ПолноеИмяФайла;
КонецЕсли;
```